# Deciding the date format in Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

Could you please help me, how can i decide the date format about this date? : **7/6/2019**
Do you know some best practices for this issue? I check the format as MM/dd/yyyy and for example if i send a message from America to Europe the date value might change to **6/7/2019** when i open it.

Comment: `7/6/2019`  is an ambiguous date. You cannot determine the format of an ambiguous date solely from the date. You must rely on information from or about the source document.  If you are using Excel, be certain the date in Excel is a "real date".  If that is not an option, format the date so it is NOT ambiguous -- eg `7-Jul-2019`.  Or use the ISO date format: `yyyy-mm-dd` formatting

Answer (score -1):

Yes, sometimes, it is quite confusing. So I used to convert the date into text to avoid that.

Here is how I do it. Once it is shown in text, it won't be changed according to the system setting.

[Here is how to convert date to text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRwPH.png)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of posting a link, please bring the relevant content here (the link can break).